# Kusto Sequencing and Summarizing events

Tags: azure-sentinel

I am working on a Splunk to Sentinel migration and I have this scenario where we have File Audit events like 4656, 4663, 4659 with different values for AccessList column and we want to merge 2 events if the AccessList value for the first event is e.g., 1537 and the AccessList value for the next event is 4424 in a timespan of 1s when Account, Computer, file_path, merge_group all these columns match in both the events.

[Example data from my lab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKoUN.png)

In Splunk they are using the command transaction e.g. : | transaction host, src_user, file_path, merge_group maxspan=1s startswith=""%%1537"" endswith=""%%4417"" keeporphans=true keepevicted=true maxevents=2

I am currently using summarize in my lab : | summarize EventsData_Xml =  make_set_if(EventData,AccessList in( '1537','4417',2 ) by bin(TimeGenerated,1s) ,Account,Computer,file_path,merge_group
The problem with this is that in make_set_if I am using the operator **in** for the predicate and it will make a set even if 2 consecutive events in a span of 1s had 4417 in AccessList column in them like this:
[Results using summarize/make_set_if](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sijsX.png)

Is there another function/command which we can use in this case where we can define the starting event and the ending event when we make the set of the events summarized in a gap of 1s when Account,Computer,file_path and merge_group columns match?

SecurityFileEvents
| summarize EventsData_Xml = make_set_if(EventData,AccessList in ('1537','4417'),2 ) by bin(TimeGenerated,1s) ,Account,Computer,file_path,merge_group
| where EventsData_Xml != '[]'
| where array_length( EventsData_Xml) >= 2

This is the query i am using where SecurityFileEvents is a function that I have created which parses the XML fields of events 4656,4659 and 4663.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Data transformations within Microsoft Sentinel

It should be relatively straightforward to consolidate the same access list id into the same column

To do this work, check out the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/configure-data-transformation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-transformations

FYI: Data transformations takes approx 1hr to apply to the API

Hope this helps